# FB is not defined using AngularJS with Facebook JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I want to use Facebook Authorization JavaScript SDK with AngularJS.

Here is my service file:

```
carApp.factory('facebook', function($window) {
    return $window.FB;
    //OR
    // return FB;
});


window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '**************',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
    });
}

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=***********&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And I get the following error in console;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
```

And it point on this line:

```
FB.init({
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is not AngularJS related. Whatever is invoking fbAsyncInit, it's probably not FB SDK. FB SDK runs fbAsyncInit after it defines `window.FB` object.

You shouldn't run fbAsyncInit yourself.

Also, keep in mind that if `facebook` factory gets instantiated before fbAsyncInit (very likely), it will return undefined (`$window.FB`)

Comment: Try to put window.fbAsyncInit function after "Load the SDK Asynchronously"